# PhpStorm seems to not allow scss file watching

Tags: node.js, sass, phpstorm, node-sass

I have a `npm run watch` job that uses node-scss to watch scss files and compile them into css files.

I use the PhpStorm IDE on Windows and when I make changes to an scss file, the file watcher (`npm run watch`) does not seem to recognise them. However if I open this same scss file in a Notepad, make changes, and save, the file watcher (`npm run watch`) recognises these changes and recompiles.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue so when I make changes to the scss file in PhpStorm the file watcher (`npm run watch`) will see them and recompile the css?

Comment: Disable "safe write" -- should help. P.S. PhpStorm have File Watcher plugin. You refer to `npm run watch` as "file watcher" as well -- it's confusing...

Comment: It's sometimes enough to click outside the code editor, if you're lucky it will synchronize and detect the change. All the intellij products have this problems since years

Comment: @LazyOne disabling safe write leads to infinite indexing. Or has this been fixed?

Comment: No idea what issue you are referring to, sorry. I'm using node-sass but with actual File Watcher plugin and not `npm run watch` .. and have no issues.

Comment: when i say file watcher, i mean my npm run watch job. SO basically somehow phpstorm does not trigger that job when i make changes to a scss file

Comment: It seems disabling safe-write fixes this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please disable `Use "safe write"` option at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings`.

- With this option **enabled**, IDE writes into temp file first, then deletes original file and only then renames temp into original name. Your `npm run watch` does not see this as file modification: it must see it differently.
- When **disabled** IDE writes new file content directly into the file (like Notepad does) hence proper "file modified" signals getting received by your watcher.

[image]